# Error : Las dimensiones de la matriz superaron el intervalo admitido. Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework

mi problema esta al cargar la solucion, un proyecto dentro de esta me sale como aparece en la imagen, "el proyecto no se pudo cargar".

Ya intente darle a volver a cargar el proyecto o recargar proyectos con dependencias y no tuvo solucion

[image: Error al cargar]

Al darle a cualquiera de esas opciones mencionadas arriba, especificamente a la opcion de "Volver a Cargar el proyecto". me salta este cartel de error

[image]

Es aqui donde no encuentro ninguna solucion, en ningun foro. Ya he intentanto tambien sacar el proyecto de la solucion y cuando quiero volver a agregarlo me sale el mismo cartel de error de Matriz.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar, Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Que tipo de proyecto es ese?, prueba abrir solo ese proyecto en lugar de la solucion completa a ver si te da un error distinto

Comment: Eso soluciono el problema, abri solo ese proyecto con VS2022 y funciono. Muchas gracias